# Javascript framework that primarily provides just document/onready functionality

Tags: javascript, frameworks, document, onready

A couple of months ago I was doing Javascript programming on the Facebook platform, on which the major frameworks such as Dojo, ExtJS, jQuery, Prototype, etc. don't necessarily work.  Which led me to discovering a couple of frameworks that merely provide the CSS selection functionality, for possible porting, namely Sizzle (used inside jQuery) and Peppy.

I remember at the time also stumbling across a mini framework that primarily provided just the document/onready functionality that some of the major frameworks provide.  However I don't remember these (well actually only one) the way I do Sizzle and/or Peppy.  Can anybody point me to such a Javascript mini framework, for providing primarily just document/onready functionality?  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was suggested to me yesterday by [Cal Jacobson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62649/cal-jacobson)

http://ryanmorr.com/archives/ondomready-no-browser-sniffing

All the best

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Going to throw in my library: [onready](https://github.com/airportyh/onready). I extracted this from jQuery.