# document.readyState analog for gecko-based browsers

Tags: javascript, dom-events, gecko, domready

IE has attribute `readyState` in document object, that indicates current state, e.g. "loading", "complete" etc.

Is there any way to find current loading state of document in Mozilla-based browsers?
I'm aware of `DOMContentLoaded` event, but it wont fit my situation, as my code can be executed after this event was fired.

Added: no, I can't use any framework, and don't confuse with `.readyState` attribute of XHR object.
And it's a bookmarklet, so it can be inserted in at any loading stage.

Added later: Anyway, it looks like it's not a big issue for me. Because this attribute [will be added in FF3.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.readyState), and it does not break things badly in Firefox, when you manipulate on unfinished DOM ([unlike IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917#more_information)).

Comment: at the end of your dynamic <script> content that can't be loaded with jQuery or the like, why not just throw on a callback? It's sloppy, but it could work.

Comment: well, it's a bookmakrlet, so no callback approach possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Sorry. But here's what you can do. If you can't test for stuff you want to be there before acting:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    // do your stuff here
}, 0);
```

(This will definitely do it after the page renders, but it might be after onload, not after DOMContentLoaded.)

If you do know how to test for what you're looking for:

```
(function () {
    if (/* test if what you're looking for is there */) {
        // do your stuff
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 0);
    }
})();
```

This will do it immediately, unless whatever you're looking for is not there, in which case it will wait until after the onload event.

**Edit:**

[Check out this solution.](http://friedcellcollective.net/outbreak/2009/02/19/jqueryreadyordone/)

What it does is, in the edge cases, checks if the last element of document.getElementsByTagName("*") is undefined or not. And that seems to work for him, even in Opera.

Comment: That will run the function before the DOM is ready in Opera, and may error out in IE as evident here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381481/is-checking-for-the-readiness-of-the-dom-overkill/#1382027

Comment: It's not perfect, but it's probably the best option, especially if the test version can be implemented. IE is a moot point, since you can check the ready state. I can live with the possible premature running in Opera as the only significant weakness.

Comment: @Anthony: what I find tricky is that Opera also supports readyState, but it is inconsistent with IE's implementation. For example, if `readyState == "interactive"`, in IE that means you can interact with the DOM (not iframes however) but in Opera the DOM still is not ready! I really would like to figure out a solution to this for all browsers.

Comment: @crescentfresh: Check out the solution I found and linked in the above post. I haven't checked, but the guy seems like he develops for Opera a lot.

Comment: @Anthony: I've yet to try the solution in that link, but from the looks of it it addresses the problem and goes into depth. Great work.

Answer (score 1):

Can be executed? Just be notified of the DOM event and store its state. I don't see what your root problem is. Surely you could rip out the guts of this method and adapt it to your situation.

jQuery's way of doing it:

```
// Mozilla, Opera and webkit nightlies currently support this event
if ( document.addEventListener ) {
    // Use the handy event callback
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){
              //do stuff
    }, false );

// If IE event model is used
} else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
    // ensure firing before onload,
    // maybe late but safe also for iframes
    document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
        if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
            document.detachEvent( "onreadystatechange", arguments.callee );
            jQuery.ready();
        }
    });

    // If IE and not an iframe
    // continually check to see if the document is ready
    if ( document.documentElement.doScroll && window == window.top ) (function(){
        if ( jQuery.isReady ) return;

        try {
            // If IE is used, use the trick by Diego Perini
            // http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/
            document.documentElement.doScroll("left");
        } catch( error ) {
            setTimeout( arguments.callee, 0 );
            return;
        }

        // and execute any waiting functions
        jQuery.ready();
    })();
}

// A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
jQuery.event.add( window, "load", jQuery.ready );
```

Comment: This code cannot detect if the document is loaded if it is itself included after the document has loaded (e.g. bookmarklet, dynamic <script> inclusion, etc), in *non*-IE browsers. I believe this is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Here's the bug report explaining what I said: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4196  Nothing has happened with it for 8 months. :(