# Delay Jquery animations after page loads

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

i have lot of animations in my website so using queryloader2 to load my entire page, but the problem i have is the animations are compleated by the time preloader loads the page and i am not able to see animations, i thought of adding some .delay() to animations but it will be no use becuase diffrent users will have diffrent loading time. is there a way to delay my animations and make them start after page loads compleately?
www.bmiconcepts.com is the url of my website

thanks in advance
regards
masood ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `load` event on `window` to ensure all data on your site (like images) are loaded completely.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    // put your code here
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381481/is-checking-for-the-readiness-of-the-dom-overkill

Answer (score 0):

this is the documentation

https://github.com/mindeavor/query-loader

```
QueryLoader.init({
  onComplete: function () {
    alert('Add animation here');
  }
});
```