# How to tell if fluent method is the last to be called

Tags: javascript, fluent

I'm trying to create a [fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)-like API for a JavaScript project.

Currently I have something like this:

```
function Foo(a, b) {
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
   this.Set = function(attr, val) {
      this[attr] = val;
      return this;
   },
   this.refresh = function() {
      //do something
   }
};
```

This allows me to write the following:

```
var foo = new Foo("Hello", "World");
// foo = { a : "Hello", b : "World" }
foo.Set("c", "!");
// foo = { a : "Hello", b : "World", c : "!" }
foo.Set(...);
//...
```

The benefit of writing a fluent API is to daisy-chain method calls, so I could more easily and readably write `foo.Set(...).Set(...).Set(...)`

Writing the basic API is fine, but I want to know how to detect the last `Set` call in the daisy-chain, because in this call I'd like to call `refresh`.

I'd like to do this to avoid the user from needing to manually append a `.refresh()`.

Has anyone dealt with something like this?

Thanks,
erip

**EDIT**

Desired effect in pseudocode:

```
function Foo(a, b) {
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
   this.Set = function(attr, val) {
      this[attr] = val;
      //if this Set is the last
         // return this.refresh();
      return this;
   },
   this.refresh = function() {
      //do something
   }
};
```

Comment: So in `foo.Set().Set().Set()` you want the first two `Set` calls to return `this`, but the last one to return something different?

Comment: @Oriol if possible, I'd like the last `Set` to be `void`, basically.

Comment: You can't. And if you can find some hack to make this work, it's probably a bad idea!

Comment: @Evert OK, I wasn't sure if there was a good way to do this. I'll have to add documentation that tells the user to forget `.refresh()` at his own risk.

Comment: Only way I can think of is using a timeout which you can clear and restart everytime the Set method is called. However,the loop won't wait for the timeout to be done.

Comment: I pulled out my bag of tricks including `setTimeout(function{},0)` (which in another setting obviates the need for document/ready in frameworks: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1381481/34806) and `new Error().stack` (which however is not standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack) -- nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

In a comment to another answer you say you would like to keep the same signature, but you might be able to do this by allowing for an optional third argument which furthermore expresses the intent to refresh, rather than just a bare boolean `true`.  The user still needs to indicate the refresh (and could accidentally call it somewhere other than the last `Set`), but it maintains the method chaining.

```
function Foo(a, b) {
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
   this.Set = function(attr, val) {
      this[attr] = val;

      var cfg = arguments[2] || {};
      if (cfg.refresh) {
         this.refresh();
      }

      return this;
   },
   this.refresh = function() {
      console.log('inside this.refresh');
   }
};

var foo = new Foo();
foo.Set("what","ever")
   .Set("Hello","World")
   .Set("United","States", {refresh: true});
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like this:

```
function Foo(a, b) {
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
   this.Set = function(attr, val, isLast) {
      this[attr] = val;
      if(isLast) {
        this.refresh();
      }
   },
   this.refresh = function() {
      //do something
   }
};

foo.Set({})
foo.Set({})
foo.Set({}, true)
```

Comment: I would like to maintain the function signature if possible.

Comment: @erip I don't think it's possible, your program has no way of automatically knowing if your done calling the Set method. You've gotta create some sort of identifier for it... parameter, function call etc..